# Polygon area to points

Tags: math, geometry, gis, geospatial

I'm trying to convert an arbitrary polygon to evenly spaced points. Due to the size of the polygon (or its bounding box) it is NOT possible to create a grid first and then test points if they are inside or outside the polygon. It must be done another way (if possible...)

Example polygon with regular grid:
[image: polygon with coordinates]

Just to repeat, the points outside of the polygon must not be tested if they are inside or outside the polygon.

Comment: I don't see clear question. What should be a result? Do you need polygon rasterization?

Comment: the result should be the points inside the polgon. Similar to a rasterization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could scan along grid lines: starting from a point a bit to the left of the polygon (ie with x less than the minimum of the vertices xs) calculate all intersections of that line with the edges and order then by x; all grid points on the line before the first intersection are outside the polygon, all between the first and the second are inside and so on. You need to do this for all grid lines with ys between the min and the max of the vertices lines, so if the polygon is big it's still a lot of processing.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution that I have come up with too (didn't get notifications about answers to my question... would have saved me time... grrr...). I calculate the intersection points of each horizontal line with the polygon and then calculate the points in between the intersection points. Used Shapely to do this.

I believe it would be even faster to run along the polygon edges calculating the points, then order them by y then x and then calculate the points in between. Should be pretty straight forward but I haven't had time to do that yet